# Kali can see USB Wifi adaptor but can't run it

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux, usb, virtualbox

I'm trying to run Kali on a VM on my Windows 10 Laptop. I've tried just about every tutorial I could find to get the adaptor working but to no avail.

Here's what I've done so far

1. Created a USB filter
2. Ejected the adaptor
3. Booted Kali in VM
4. Plugged the adaptor back in.

I have checked the device under *Devices > USB*. Windows also isn't using the device. When I run *lsusb* I get this output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b711 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Clearly, Kali can see the adaptor but I can't get WiFi to work. Any ideas? The adaptor is a Tenda W3M11MI

Comment: The best tutorial on kail follows "Don't use kail as your first Gnu/Linux operating system, learn another first. Don't use it as your main OS, use it only for what it is designed for."

Comment: Any logs relevant to this? You're gonna need to do some more troubleshooting. What errors do you get, etc.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Kali isn't my first. I primarily use Linux Mint and I'm getting the same errors there.

Comment: @Panki there are no errors. Nothing goes wrong the adaptor just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a Tenda W311MI then Google suggests that the only way to get this working is to use the drivers available on Tenda's own website

https://www.tendacn.com/en/download/detail-2653.html

Unfortunately the `README` reports that it's only for kernel series 2.4 or 2.6, so I suspect your solution to this problem will be to return the adapter and buy a compatible one.

Comment: I tried rebuilding their Linux driver and yes it didn't work. Tenda sells two versions of this adaptor. One universal one and another windows exclusive one. I got the latter and that's just been a waste of time and money.